# Bad question about gaming?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I see all kind of people(including some of my friends) that simply don't know when to stop playing(for instance, wake up, play wow, eat ,play wow ,eat , play wow , sleep). Lather, Rinse, Repeat.

I realized that myself spend way to much time on games. Now, would it be fit to ask a question about this problem, something like: What are some good ways to organize your time while playing games so this doesn't become a problem for you. or What amount of maximum time should you be playing a day. Well, a question with the same idea.

I **know** this probably wouldn't be a good question, but maybe I can create a good question which would concern the same problem and post it here? And if not, which of the stackExchange sites would be fit for such a question?

Thanks a lot and sorry for this unconventional question.

Comment: I wouldn't have a problem with it. Gamer questions are on-topic.

Comment: Thanks for bringing it to Meta first.  @badp Is it a gamer question, though?  Seems to me that time/addiction management is largely independent of whatever it is you're overdoing, and requires expertise other than gaming expertise to answer.

Comment: For the record, we've got a similar question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1372/techniques-to-deal-with-game-addiction

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://productivity.stackexchange.com/ should be a good fit for what you're seeking. It's still in beta, so your question probably won't get a quick answer, but it's definitely worth a shot.

Comment: Hey that's actually what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Question link for those interested: http://productivity.stackexchange.com/q/3217/2352